# Opening links in txt file in headless browser in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, google-chrome-headless, snort

I have been having a problem running the code below and suspect the problem is with link.strip(). The program is running in a linux environment and it is supposed to open multiple links contained in a text files and opens them for snort to scan for malware. The file name is defined in the terminal before the code is executed.

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
import argparse

def read_links_from_file(file_path):
    links = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            links.append(line.strip())
    return links

def open_links_in_chrome(links, headless=True):
    options = '--headless' if headless else ''
    for link in links:
        subprocess.call('google-chrome {options} --app={link}', shell=True)
        time.sleep(1)

def run_snort(interface):
    subprocess.call(f'snort -i {interface}', shell=True)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--file', help='Path to file containing links', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--interface', help='Network interface for Snort to listen on', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--headless', help='Run Chrome in headless mode', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    file_path = args.file
    interface = args.interface
    headless = args.headless
    
    links = read_links_from_file(file_path)
    snort_process = subprocess.Popen(['snort', '-i', interface])
    open_links_in_chrome(links, headless)
    snort_process.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried reconfiguring the applications and rewrote the code but I'm not sure if I preserved the right code but

```
links.append(line.strip())
```

doesn't seem to be the right way to go. I have also changed the sleep time from 5 to 1

After some tinkering I ended up with the following error

*Acquiring network traffic from "eth0". ERROR: Can't start DAQ (-1) - socket: Operation not permitted! Fatal Error, Quitting.. libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name
= (null) [121024:121024:0217/122814.243731:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(49)] dri3 extension not supported. [121070:8:0217/122815.025776:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer. Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been having a problem running the code below and suspect the problem is with link.strip().

I assume you mean `line.strip()` (you're not calling `link.strip()` anywhere in your code). If you think the code is problematic, let's test it. If I have a file that contains a list of four URLs in file `urls.txt`:

```
https://google.com
https://stackoverflow.com
https://www.npr.org/programs/wait-wait-dont-tell-me/
https://www.nyan.cat/
```

And then run the following code:

```
import sys

def read_links_from_file(file_path):
    links = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            links.append(line.strip())
    return links

links = read_links_from_file('urls.txt')
for i, link in enumerate(links):
    print(f'{i}: {link}')
```

I get the following output:

```
0: https://google.com
1: https://stackoverflow.com
2: https://www.npr.org/programs/wait-wait-dont-tell-me/
3: https://www.nyan.cat/
```

That suggest your `read_links_from_file` function works as expected.

On the other hand, you're doing more work than is necessary. The default behavior of a Python file object is to act as an iterator over the lines in the file, so instead of writing this:

```
def read_links_from_file(file_path):
    links = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            links.append(line.strip())
    return links

links = read_links_from_file(args.file)
open_links_in_chrome(links, args.headless)
```

You can just delete the `read_links_from_file` functions and pass the open file:

```
with open(args.file) as links:
  open_links_in_chome((line.strip() for line in links), args.headless)
```

I'm cheating a bit here because in stead of simply iterating over the file I'm using a generator expression to take care of stripping the end-of-line character.

---

You have an error in your `open_links_in_chrome` function. You have written:

```
subprocess.call('google-chrome {options} --app={link}', shell=True)
```

This will result in running the *literal* command line...

```
chrome {options} --app={link}
```

...because you are neither using a Python [f-string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) nor are you calling the [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method. You need to write the function like this in order to run Chrome as expected:

```
def open_links_in_chrome(links, headless=True):
    options = '--headless' if headless else ''
    for link in links:
        subprocess.call(f'google-chrome {options} --app={link}', shell=True)
        time.sleep(1)
```

This introduces a new problem: this will successfully open Chrome with the first URL, but Chrome will never exit, so your code won't continue past this point.

Rather than trying to fix this, I would suggest using a browser automation library like [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/) or [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Here's your code rewritten to use Playwright:

```
import playwright
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

import subprocess
import time
import argparse
import signal

def open_links_in_chrome(links, headless=True):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=headless)
        page = browser.new_page()
        for link in links:
            print(f'fetching {link}')
            try:
                page.goto(link)
            except playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError:
                print(f'{link} timed out.')
            time.sleep(1)
        browser.close()

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--file', help='Path to file containing links', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--interface', help='Network interface for Snort to listen on', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--headless', help='Run Chrome in headless mode', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    snort_process = subprocess.Popen(['snort', '-i', args.interface])
    with open(args.file) as links:
        open_links_in_chrome((line.strip() for line in links), headless=args.headless)
    snort_process.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If we run this -- assuming we have followed the Playwright installation instructions -- we see as output:

```
fetching https://google.com
fetching https://stackoverflow.com
fetching https://www.npr.org/programs/wait-wait-dont-tell-me/
fetching https://www.nyan.cat/
```

In my tests I've replaced `snort` with `tcpdump`, and examining the resulting packet capture I can see that we're making the expected network requests:

```
$ tcpdump -r packets port 53 | grep -E 'A\? (google.com|stackoverflow.com|www.npr.org|www.nyan.cat)'
reading from file packets, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144
20:23:37.319272 IP madhatter.52135 > _gateway.domain: 52609+ A? stackoverflow.com. (35)
20:23:38.811385 IP madhatter.39144 > _gateway.domain: 15910+ AAAA? www.npr.org. (29)
20:23:38.811423 IP madhatter.52655 > _gateway.domain: 13756+ A? www.npr.org. (29)
20:23:41.214261 IP madhatter.46762 > _gateway.domain: 20587+ AAAA? www.nyan.cat. (30)
20:23:41.214286 IP madhatter.43846 > _gateway.domain: 12335+ A? www.nyan.cat. (30)
```

Comment: I'll try this right away. Will there be a performative difference between selenium and playwright?

Comment: I don't know enough about the differences between selenium and playwright to answer that question.

Comment: The code worked but snort threw me the usual 

ERROR: Can't start DAQ (-1) - socket: Operation not permitted!

Comment: Perhaps you need to be running `snort` as `root`?

Comment: I did that and it threw 

WARNING: No preprocessors configured for policy 0

Comment: That sounds like more of a snort issue than a Python issue. I'm not familiar with Snort.